# Is there a travel site for Belgium that can search all bus operators, but exclude trains?

Tags: online-resources, buses, belgium

I have found out I can use *nmbs.be* to search for buses of both *delijn.be* and *infotec.be*. The 'problem' is that it also includes trains no matter what you choose in the advanced options.

Is there any search engine that allows searching for just buses?

The reason that I am asking is that I am trying to figure out the cheapest route between two points and as both *TEC* and *De Lijn* have relatively cheap long distance/day passes (less than the sum of a bus ticket + train ticket + bus ticket) I am trying to find a route between Leuven and Charleroi Airport by bus. Additionally Google Maps only includes buses from *De Lijn* and I have been unable to find any other service.

Comment: I checked the nmbs.be option, but if you click on more, you have the option "Products", "Only bus, tram, metro". Does that not work for you?

Comment: @Bernhard: First of all, shame on me, you're right. I was expecting a kind of check list like the one on delijn.be (though that one doesn't work for TEC buses giving a 'technical error') and due to that somehow inconceivably missed the list on nmbs.be. You can if you want post your comment as an answer or otherwise I will just delete this question entirely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the advanced options of [belgianrail.be](http://www.belgianrail.be/jp/sncb-nmbs-routeplanner/query.exe/en?HWAI=VIEW!advanced=yes!&) one has the following product options

- Domestic trains only
- All products, including international trains
- All products, without international trains
- Only bus, tram, metro

The last one should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Since the closing of Railtime (the API used for NMBS/SNCB by among other Google Maps), now all public transport in Belgium searched with Google Maps will only feature buses and trams.

EDIT: since then NMBS/SNCB has opened up to Google and trains are also in Google Maps. [source (Dutch)](http://www.belgianrail.be/nl/nieuws/dienstregeling-googlemaps.aspx)

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Source that trains are ignored: https://i.imgur.com/nbgodhh.png Would regularly display trains, but now doesn't, and if you look for other directions to for example Bruges/Brussels it would use the Dutch trains